# font is grainy on new monitors

Tags: display

I purchased two AOC E2470Sw monitors which had decent reviews.  On both of them, the text looks weird.  I noticed it when I plugged it in and compared against my earlier monitors.

I have adjusted the contrast and brightness many times.  I have done this in the monitor menu as well as in Windows.  The difference is subtle but enough that it's all I see when I'm reading.  I held the clear type options a few times but each time it doesn't seem to do anything.  I have two of these monitors and they are both having the same issues.  It's like... there is a haze around the letters.  Sharpness doesn't fix it.  It's like dark, or looks like the letters are not crisp around the background.  I can't show my screen because it would just look like what yours looks like.  I can try to post photographs of the monitors?  The shading just doesn't look right.

Both monitors are using VGA cables.  I have used VGA cables on different monitors and they are fine.  There is a hdmi to vga adapter additionally.

I actually don't know how to describe it.  It's not that it's blurry.  It's that it's crisp but tough to read?  Does that make sense?  Like the letters are stretching?  I feel like I'm taking crazy pills.

I see this weird echo or alter image when i look at text on this monitor which does not happen on other monitors.

I have some snags for you.

Here is the good monitor. See how the text is clear:

[image]

The picture below is from the new monitor.  Look at the base of the I and the n and t and how it's all asymmetrical

[image]

So, I have some text that is half on my previous monitor and half on my new monitor.  When I turn clear type off, they both pretty much look the same.  When I turn it on, it makes it look better on the other monitor, but doesn't do much on the new monitor which is like it's ignoring the fact that I've gone through the options many times.

Any tips?

Comment: First tip - lose the VGA cables & use something from the 21st Century instead:/ That alone will probably fix the ghosting.

Comment: The VGA cables have been fine on other monitors and are not the problem.

Comment: check your GPU driver for anything related to "overdraw scaling" and disable it. Should not be an issue via VGA, but...

Comment: Also, make sure that screen resolution is fixed to 1920 x 1080, from the windows display options. Plus, visit this page : http://betanews.com/2015/10/05/how-to-fix-windows-10s-blurry-font-problem/

Comment: Some settings have not been changed.  I can plug in another monitor and it's fine.  It's just the ones I bought that looks unusual.  It's 1920.

Comment: That page links to this page http://windows10_dpi_blurry_fix.xpexplorer.com/ however it is very hard to read on my new monitor but looks awesome on my previous monitor.  They are running at the same time. @iSR5

Comment: @try them on another computer (like using your laptop) also try using HDMI rather than VGA, to test if the monitor VGA has issues or not. As you test the VGA cables on other monitor and worked fine, so maybe the new monitors have VGA problems.

Comment: I'm connecting them to my laptop at the moment.  Laptop has a VGA and hdmi output.  Monitors are vga and dvi.

Comment: It is hard to see on your photos, but could the subpixels be out-of-order on your monitor? Right-click your desktop, select `Personalize`, click `Display` link on the bottom left, then click `Adjust ClearType text` in the top left corner. Follow the dialog selecting better-looking options. Is it better now? If it is, please post a screenshot (not a photo) of any text on your screen.

Comment: Another page that is very hard to read on the new monitor https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1743562 although it looks better in firefox than in internet explorer

Comment: Jack White I cannot post a screenshot because that will display how it looks on your monitor.  To give an example, I can take a screenshot on my grainy monitor and move it over to the old monitor and it looks just fine.  I have set clear type multiple times and it doesn't seem to switch anything.

Comment: Another observation, the new monitor defaulted to 59hz which I set to 60hz.  And it says it's a television rather than a monitor.  Altering these settings made no difference.

Comment: So I assume "adjust cleartype" did not help much? If it did, a screenshot would reveal what exactly it did which may be useful for further troubleshooting. Also ensure that your display resolution is set to exactly1920x1080. VGA itself is suboptimal for such wide resolutions, so at least some horizontal blurring is to be expected. Try auto-adjusting the monitor. Try lowering both brightness and contrast to 50%.

Comment: Hey, clear type did not do much at all.  In fact, when I turn it off it doesn't even really change much on that monitor, edit= yes it does, but it does on my early monitor.  I have it set to the native.  I've moved the contrast and stuff around too.

Comment: The cleartype settings appear not to have much of a change on Internet Explorer in that monitor despite changing Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot attach images to comments so decided to post this as a *possible* answer.

### Subpixel arrangement

[Subpixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) is a technique which utilizes a quirk found in most monitors' physical hardware to have clearer-than-normally-possible text. However, if its settings do not match your monitor, the text will look especially ugly while everything else looks fine.

Please view this image below *very closely* on both of your monitors. On one of the edges of a cyan square you should see a **tiny** dark line between cyan and red, and on the opposite side there should be no such line - note which side it is.

[image: subpixel test image]

On some monitors there may be a dark line on one side, no line on the opposite side, and thinner less dark lines on two remaining sides - ignore those last two.

On your old monitor the dark line is most likely on the left edge which would indicate it has `RGB` subpixel arrangement. Most desktop monitors are like this. If on your new monitor it is on a different edge - this is what causes your troubles.

Dark line on the left edge indicates `RGB` subpixel arrangement, right edge - `BGR`, top edge - `V-RGB`, bottom edge - `V-BGR`. More info [here](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/subpixel.php).

"Adjust ClearType" wizard should normally tune your system for your monitor, however in practice not all programs actually adhere to those settings, including some of Microsoft own software. You may also need to reboot for it to take more effect.

Also, ClearType tuning to fit one type of the monitor makes it look awful on the other. If you need to use multiple monitors with different subpixel arrangements at the same time, you are pretty much out of luck. Some programs support this but [most don't](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ff4b930a-cb5a-40c5-b89e-1492bf30b192/is-cleartype-able-to-support-both-rgb-and-bgr-sub-pixel-panel-displays-at-the-same-time?forum=w8itprogeneral). You may have to turn ClearType off - however this causes text to lose some sharpness on both monitors, often requires [registry editing](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/disable-all-font-smoothing-in-windows-7-ie/f180e803-3317-4433-8fd2-63aadaecc2d2) for many programs, and would still not work properly everywhere.

If your new monitor has a dark line on the right side, which means `BGR` arrangement, and an old one has it on the left, which is `RGB`, a stupidly-looking but working way to get around the problem would be rotating the new monitor upside-down, and then rotating its picture right-side-up through video-card display settings. Some monitors can be unscrewed from their base stand and rotated this way, others could be wall-mounted upside down. After doing this you need to re-run ClearType Adjustment for both monitors and the text should look fine on both. The only other option would be to get rid of one monitor type or another.

If the red-cyan border looks blurred on the left and right edge, or dark lines look almost identical on opposite edges, read on:

### Dot clock

The next test may help detecting if your video-card DAC, cable, or monitor ADC are good enough to transfer the image signal at right time, so that your screen displays exactly the pixels your video-card outputs.

Right click the following image, select "save image as", and view (100% size) on you new monitor.

> Note: At least in Mozilla Firefox browser it is displayed incorrectly for me, however it works in Google Chrome. Windows built-in picture viewer should display it normally.

[image: dot monitor test]

It looks like a gray rectange, but in fact is a pattern of one-pixel black and white dots. It should look **uniform** horizontally and vertically. If you see vertical gray bands like in the image below (also save it and view it with a standard viewer), or you see a dot crawling effect (like a slowly scrolling animation), either your video-card or your VGA cable is inadequate for the monitor. Sometimes this can be fixed by fine-tuning the display device (Try adjusting `width`, `dot clock` and `phase` settings in your monitor's OSD menu. Do a factory reset if you mess it up.)

[image: bad cable problem looks like this]

If you see cross-hatched (`++++++`-like) gray pattern like one on the picture below, this likely indicates your resolution is incorrect.

[image: bad resolution problem looks like this]

### Other tests

[Lagom.nl](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/) website has some of the monitor tests you could try, including the ones above. Please report if you have abnormal results on some of them. Some test images above were recreated from that site.

Comment: The OP says switching monitors looks great on the one not the other. To me this sounds like the two monitors have different subpixel arrangement. So I think you are probably correct. Also, reporting as a "television" makes me even more suspicious of overdraw/underdraw scaling, which is usually performed after rendering (especially in applications with their own font rendering, read: Office, Browsers etc.)

Comment: OP should check the color calibration and gamma also.